# Google Apps Scripts how to use variable as A1 notation in setFormula

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to setFormula by app script. In my script, I get last row number as variable "row3" and this "row3" will be used in setFormula. As only has "row3" and fixed column nubmer, I think I have to use A1 notation in the setFormula. For example, if my last raw is "20" meaning "row3"="20". I want to setFormula to be "if cell (20,10) is empty, then return "0" to cell (20,2), otherwise return "1" to cell (20,2). Here is my code.

```
var sheet3 = ss2.getSheetByName("Message").activate();
    sheet3.appendRow();
var row3 = sheet3.getLastRow();

    sheet3.getRange(row3,2).setFormula('if((${row3},10)="",0,1)');
```

Comment: What is the formula  you're trying to set? `=if((20,10)="",do this,  else this )` is invalid formula syntax. How about you come up with the correct formula first before trying to setFormula it? Think: What's the formula I'm trying to set in Google sheets. Open up a sheet and write a plain if formula there to see if it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You have a `R1C1` notation and want to transform it to an `A1` notation before  setting the formula

In Apps Script one of the easier ways to do it is with [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column) in combination with [getA1Notation()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#geta1notation).

Sample:

```js
  var cellNotation = sheet3.getRange(row3,10).getA1Notation();
  sheet3.getRange(row3,2).setFormula('if('+cellNotation+'="",0,1)');
```

Comment: The question does't include valid R1C1 notation. If the OP is actually trying to use R1C1 the easier solution is to use `setFormulaR1C1`

Comment: That's also possible, but I believe the OP was asking about how to obtain A1 notation.

Comment: Actually I did not know setFormulaR1C1, however the syntax works.